Laurent expansion at $z = -1$
I want to get to the Laurent expansion of $g(z) = \frac{z^2 + 4z + 4}{z+1}$ at $z = -1$.
I know $g(z) = \frac{(z+2)^2}{z+1}$.
I tried computing the Taylor-Series for $g(-1)$ and getting
$g(-1)+ g'(-1) \times (z-(-1))  + \frac{g''(-1)}{2} \times (z-(-1))^2 + \frac{g''(-1)}{6} \times (z-(-1))^3 + ...$
But as $g'(z) = \frac{z(z+2)}{(z+1)^2}$ I can't insert $z = -1$ in $g'(z), g''(z), \dots$, right?
Laurent-Expansion calculators show me the result for the expansion is $z + \frac{1}{z+1} + 3$, how do I get there? I am totally lost on this one.

Well, $g$ does not have a Taylor series centered at $z=-1$ at all, otherwise asking for a Laurent expansion would just be a trick question.

Do you know about the uniqueness of Laurent series?

@okaberintarou, do you mean that the $a_n$ of the laurent series are uniquely determined via an integral function?

@SassatelliGiulio Thank you! At least I know now that the T.E. is not the correct way here :D

Indeed it can be calculated by integrals, but here the uniqueness guarantees that any simple methods work: for example, the Laurent series of $z^2+4z+4$ at $z=-1$ would be $(z+1)^2 + 2(z+1) + 1$ by simple algebra.

@okaberintarou I'm sorry, but what do you mean by simple methods work? Isn't the Laurent series of $z^2 + 4z + 4$ at $z = -1$ the taylor expansion of it, as it's analytical? Or is there another way of determining the laurent expansion without given boundaries? I'm very sorry if I don't get it immediately..
Edit: Wait, can I now just calculate $\frac{1}{z+1} * (z+1)^2 + 2(z+1) + 1$ and arrive at the wanted Laurent series?
Would the laurent series then be $(z+1) + 2 + (z+1)$ ? Different from wolframalpha but another calculator shows me this result?
Is it that simple?

Yes, if you check the definition, you actually don't even need uniqueness to get that answer. I just mentioned it because it provides some comfort knowing that there is only one Laurent series satisfying the definition, so you can be confident that your calculation is not strange if its value near the base point is the same.

A Laurent series expansion at $z=-1$ is given by
\begin{align*}
g(z)=\sum_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}a_n(z+1)^n
\end{align*}
We can easily obtain this representation from the representation of $g(z)$ as a rational function, since
\begin{align*}
\color{blue}{g(z)}=\frac{(z+2)^2}{z+1}&=\frac{\left((z+1)+1\right)^2}{z+1}\\
&=\frac{(z+1)^2+2(z+1)+1}{z+1}\\
&\,\,\color{blue}{=(z+1)+2+\frac{1}{z+1}}
\end{align*}
